# How to uninstall ELK filebeat from kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat

i try to uninstall the [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-kubernetes.html) from kubernetes
but i can't find anywhere how to uninstall it
how can safely uninstall it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the filebeat deamonset.
`kubectl delete ds filebeat`

Comment: Thanks ! , will it delete me the filebeat ConfigMap, access control RoleBinding and all related to filebeat ?

Comment: nope, you'll have to delete them separately or you can see what's the common label across resources and delete based on labels, something like:
`kubectl delete all -l app=filebeat`

Comment: can you look at this question please :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561985/filebeat-data-path-already-locked-by-another-beat-please-make-sure-that-multi