# Filebeat : data path already locked by another beat. Please make sure that multiple beats are not sharing the same data path

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Looking at the logs in one of the filebeat pods i can see this:

```
2021-01-04T10:10:52.754Z        DEBUG   [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/providers.go:129     add_cloud_metadata: fetchMetadata ran for 2.351101ms
2021-01-04T10:10:52.754Z        INFO    [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/add_cloud_metadata.go:93     add_cloud_metadata: hosting provider type detected as openstack, metadata={"ava
ilability_zone":"us-east-1c","instance":{"id":"i-08f536567bd9945df","name":"ip-10-101-2-178.ec2.internal"},"machine":{"type":"m5.2xlarge"},"provider":"openstack"}
2021-01-04T10:10:52.755Z        DEBUG   [processors]    processors/processor.go:120     Generated new processors: add_cloud_metadata={"availability_zone":"us-east-1c","instance":{"id":"i-08f5
36567bd9945df","name":"ip-10-101-2-178.ec2.internal"},"machine":{"type":"m5.2xlarge"},"provider":"openstack"}, add_docker_metadata=[match_fields=[] match_pids=[process.pid, process.ppid]]    
2021-01-04T10:10:52.755Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:392    filebeat stopped.
2021-01-04T10:10:52.755Z        ERROR   instance/beat.go:956    Exiting: data path already locked by another beat. Please make sure that multiple beats are not sharing the same data path (pat
h.data).
Exiting: data path already locked by another beat. Please make sure that multiple beats are not sharing the same data path (path.data).
```

as you can see the filebeat stopped with an error :

```
data path already locked by another beat. Please make sure that multiple beats are not sharing the same data path (path.data).
```

After searching the problem in github/forum i found this :
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/data-path-already-locked-by-another-beat/219852/4

Which looks like my problem,
Im using the default filebeat-kubernetes.yaml , and there is no information in ELK / Filebeats docs on how to add unique paths in the filebeat-kubernetes.yaml
where do i add them and how do i make them unique?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. It means that your data path (/var/lib/filebeats) are locked by another filebeat instance. So execute `sudo systemctl stop filebeat` (in my case) to ensure that you don't have running filebeat
and then run filebeat with `sudo filebeat -e` which prints logs in console

I also tried link, that you shared, but it didn't help me. Here another solutions, may be it would help you: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/data-path-already-locked-by-another-beat/219852/2

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Anton's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66919142/4896913), In one of the scenarios, I had a lock file in the data path. This could be  `/var/lib/filebeat/filebeat.lock` depending on the configuration. Delete the file and run `sudo filebeat -e`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Elastic stack as a service, the solution is just to restart all of the stack in this order:

- Elasticsearch
- Kibana
- Logstash
- Filebeat(s)

which is already suggested in [this link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/solved-data-path-already-locked-by-another-beat/262018).